# Can a constructor look like this in Java?

Tags: java, constructors

I wonder if a constructor in Java can look like this:

```
public double[] values;
```

I'm not sure if the constructor can look like this, or should it be

```
public values (double[] values){
    values = someValues;
}
```

Comment: Neither of those are valid constructors in this case.  The first is a valid field declaration, where `public` is the access modifier, `double[]` is the type, and `values` is the name of the field.  For the second, I don't believe that will compile.  it looks like your classname is `values`, but you also have `values` as the methods parameter `double[] values`.  I think I'm a little confused as to what you're looking to do, are you looking to take in a `double[]` in the constructor and set a local field to those values?

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually trying to achieve with these constructors. What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 2):

Nope. This

```
public double[] values;
```

just declares a public array of doubles named values.

And this

```
public values (double[] values){
    values = someValues;
}
```

fails even when properly indented. It still isn't right because you didn't define the class name. Even if you did declare `values` inside a class named `values` you still messed up. Because while it might work as a constructor in this

```
class values {    
    public double[] values;

    public values (double[] values){
        values = someValues;
    }
}
```

values is a horrible name for a class. Bleh. Capitalize class names, don't plurize them, and for pete sake make them more descriptive than `values`. Oh and you never defined `someValues`.

To see what forms are and are not allowed as constructors I encourage you to look at the [Java specification for them](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8).

> ConstructorDeclaration:
>   {ConstructorModifier} ConstructorDeclarator [Throws] ConstructorBody
>
> ConstructorDeclarator:
>   [TypeParameters] SimpleTypeName ( [FormalParameterList] )
>
> SimpleTypeName:
>   Identifier

It gives this example:

```
class Point {
    int x, y;
    Point(int x, int y) { this.x = x; this.y = y; }
}
```